# Kubernetes dashboard ingress HTTP error 400

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Installed Kubernetes dashboard with Helm

```
helm install kubernetes-dashboard kubernetes-dashboard/kubernetes-dashboard -f values.yaml --create-namespace -n kubernetes-dashboard
```

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /
  hosts:
    - kubedash.labs.example.com
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
  tls:
    - secretName: ca-wildcard-example-cert-secret
      hosts:
        - kubedash.labs.example.com
  metricsScraper:
    enabled: true
  metrics-server:
    enabled: true

protocolHttp: true
## Additional container arguments
##
extraArgs:
  # - --enable-skip-login
  - --enable-insecure-login
# - --system-banner="Welcome to Kubernetes"
```

Kuberetes dashboard ingress returns

```
curl -I https://kubedash.labs.example.com
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.21.6
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2022 18:39:17 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Nginx ingress version 2.3.0 installed via Helm.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `--enable-insecure-login` made it to work on HTTPS via ingress, its kinda insecure but do the trick

whole config :

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /
  hosts:
    - kubedash.labs.example.com
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
  tls:
    - secretName: ca-wildcard-example-cert-secret
      hosts:
        - kubedash.labs.example.com
  metricsScraper:
    enabled: true
  metrics-server:
    enabled: true

protocolHttp: true
## Additional container arguments
##
extraArgs:
  # - --enable-skip-login
  - --enable-insecure-login
  # - --system-banner="Welcome to Kubernetes"
```